# A bit of confusion on compact operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I know that given a linear operator $S \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ and a compact operator $T \in \mathcal{B}(X)$, it is clear since a compact operator is a two-sided ideal, then $ST, TS$ are also compact.

What isn't so clear to me is a proposition that assuming $T$ is compact, it follows that $S(I-T)= I$ iff $(I-T)S = I$, where $I$ is the identity operator. I tried proving this only with the fact that $ST$ is also compact, but so far have not been very successful in either direction. How would you suggest I proceed? Maybe I just need to also consider $TS$, which is also compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is invoking theorem 4.25 of Rudin, which says that for $T$ compact, you have

$$\dim \ker (I-T) = \dim (X/\mathcal{R}(I-T)).$$

Then if you have $S(I-T) = I$, that directly tells you that $I-T$ is injective, hence by theorem 4.25 it is surjective, hence invertible, and $S = (I-T)^{-1}$, whence $(I-T)S = I$. If you start from $(I-T)S = I$, you immediately have surjectivity of $I-T$, and by 4.25 injectivity, hence invertibility, and $S=(I-T)^{-1}$.

Comment: OK, I thought I was doing something wrong because in the second part of 9(b) which I "proved," as silly as it seems, I went straight ahead with assuming invertibility which I could not have done unless I actually showed surjectivity which was the key here.